# Who changed the response._content_consumed to True when debuging testing case of python requests

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-requests, pdb

When I read the source code of the [requests](https://github.com/requests/requests) I try to debug the testing case for tracing code with vscode and python extension.
When I run the `test_digestauth_401_count_reset_on_redirect` function in *test_lowlevel.py*, I encounter a weird question.After getting the first response of four from the internal Server thread,the registered hook function `handle_401` is called and if I set a breakpoint at the line of `r.content` in `handle_401` I found that the 'r._content_consumer' is **True**.But before the `r.content`, the result of executing `print(r._content_consumed)` is **False**. I don't know why and who set the `r._content_consumed` to True.

And then I debug the same code with pdb, everything is OK. both `print(r._content_consumed)` and `pdb p r._content_consumed` are False.

Environment:
OS Version: Win10 64bit

Python Version:3.6.1

VSCode Version:1.9.1 ia32

Python extension:0.9.1

[image: print statement and breakpoint]
[image: debug val content and print result]